# BigQuery - How to unnest multiple nested values

Tags: google-bigquery

[image: schema]

I am trying to Select the two values I have highlighted in the image (attributes.price.list.item.net AND attributes.price.list.item.listPrice.gross)

I am using the following snippet but it just flattens the whole list array and returns every column within. If I try to unnest any other way, I only get errors. How can I unnest multiple nested arrays like this?

```
SELECT attributes.price.list
FROM my_table LEFT JOIN UNNEST(attributes.price.list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT 
  el.item.net,
  el.item.listPrice.gross
FROM my_table 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(attributes.price.list) el
```